# Is there a possibility to convert files in python using the os module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, type-conversion

I want to convert different files with different mime types to other mime types. For example all my videos(mp4, mov, ...) shall be converted into mp4s and all my images(jpg, svg gif and so on) shall be converted into jpgs. Is there a possibility to do this in a clean and minimalist way without using additional modules?

I have already done some research, but I only found discussions dealing with conversion of strings to binary or something like that.
I am very new to python, so I would be happy about some help with that problem.

Comment: Have you done any research already?

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a minimal code example on what you have tried so far? Please go through : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: have already done some research, but I only found discussions dealing with conversion of strings to binary or something like that.

Comment: os gives you access to generalised OS operations. So things you can do from the command-line... subprocess allows you to call another program and delegate the responsibility of the processing to that external program. Another approach would be to use libraries - checkout pypi there are lots of packages available on there. A quick search finds  https://pypi.org/project/PythonVideoConverter/ which is a wrapper for ffmpeg.

Comment: all right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin `subprocess` module to run an external command. It doesn't require Python dependencies, but the system you run on should have `ffmpeg`. For images conversion you can use `convert`.

Examples:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'my-video.mov', '-vcodec', 'h264', '-acodec', 'mp2', 'my-video.mp4'])
subprocess.run(['convert', 'image.jpg', 'image.png'])
```

You can find more docs on the convertors for different formats.